# how to have a slideshow of images in windows phone application development

Tags: c#, windows-phone, slideshow

I am building my first app for windows phone application with visual C# 2010.

- I want to have a slideshow of images in a page
- In that slideshow when the image is clicked i want to navigate to another page.

I googled it but didnt get much help. What i tried is:

```
void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    LoadImages();
}

private void LoadImages()
{
    Image.Add("Image/aaa.jpg");
    Image.Add("Image/bbb.jpg");
    Image.Add("Image/ccc.jpg");
    Image.Add("Image/ddd.jpg");
}
```

I wrote these code in the design page of the page where i need the slideshow of images.

Comment: the path where my pic is stored.

Comment: in a blog i got of adding a timer control to my form but i dont have any such control in my tool box

Comment: Timer is for windows form, I don't know if it is available for windows phone

Comment: So can you please help how to proceed?

Comment: Sorry I can't, I'm a winform guy, I have never done windows phone development. I might be able to answer for winform but not windows phone

Comment: what kind of slideshow are you looking for, Please elaborate a bit

Comment: i have 4 images which i want to change after say 1 or 2secs. after 1 or 2 secs i want the next image to show

Comment: @bhaskar07 have you checked the updated code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check this sample.

Add an Image in **MainPage.xaml**

```
<Grid x:Name="ContentPanel" Grid.Row="1" Margin="12,0,12,0">
        <Image x:Name="Img" Height="400" Tap="Img_OnTap" ></Image>
</Grid>
```

Do the following in **MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
    private List<string> _images;
    /// <summary>
    /// List of images
    /// </summary>
    public List<string> Images
    {
        get { return _images; }
        set { _images = value; }
    }

    //selected image index
    public int SelectedImageIndex { get; set; }

    // Constructor
    public MainPage()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
      this.Loaded += MainPage_Loaded;
      this.DataContext = this;
    }

   void MainPage_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
   {
        LoadImages();
        DispatcherTimer t = new DispatcherTimer();
        //setting a 5 second interval
        t.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 5); 
        t.Tick += t_Tick;
        t.Start();
    }

    void t_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (SelectedImageIndex == Images.Count-1)
            SelectedImageIndex = 0;
        else
            SelectedImageIndex++;

        SetImageSource(Images[SelectedImageIndex]);
    }

    //Populating image list
    private void LoadImages()
    {
        if (Images == null)
            Images = new List<string>();
        Images.Add("/Image/aaa.jpg");
        Images.Add("/Image/bbb.jpg");
        Images.Add("/Image/ccc.jpg");
        Images.Add("/Image/ddd.jpg");
        SelectedImageIndex = 0;
        SetImageSource(Images[SelectedImageIndex]);
    }

    //setting image source
    private void SetImageSource(string imagePath)
    {
        Img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(imagePath, UriKind.RelativeOrAbsolute));
    }

    //Image tap event
    private void Img_OnTap(object sender, GestureEventArgs e)
    {
        string selectedImagePath = Images[SelectedImageIndex];
        //Put your navigation here
    }
```

Comment: there is some problem.

Comment: the application stops after a few secs and showed an error in SetImageSource(Images[SelectedImageIndex]);                            error is arguments out of reach

Comment: i am new member here. anyways thanks for your help. its working fine now. how to mark answered??

Comment: @bhaskar07 There is a Tick Mark on the Left side of my answer [just below the Down arrow mark].  Just tick it.

Comment: i am working on this domain just from last week and need to complete a project by this week. Can you please help me in learning web service

Answer (score 0):

You can create your own slide show with timer and a listbox control try this

Your xaml Code should be

```
<ListBox  Grid.Row="1" Name="listControlImage" SelectionChanged="listControlImage_SelectionChanged">
      <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      <DataTemplate>
      <Image  Height="600" Width="460" Stretch="Fill" Source="{Binding}"/>
  </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
      </DataTemplate>
```

your code behind code should be

//global variables

```
List<BitmapImage> ListImages = new List<BitmapImage>();
 DispatcherTimer Timer = new DispatcherTimer();
int SlideCount=0;

void Page1_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
  LoadImages();
  DisTimer.Tick += DisTimer_Tick;
  DisTimer.Interval = new TimeSpan(0, 0, 1);
  DisTimer.Start();
}

private void LoadImages()
{
  ListImages.Add( new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Your project name;component/Image/aaa.jpg", UriKind.Relative))); 
 ListImages.Add( new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Your project name;component/Image/bbb.jpg", UriKind.Relative))); 
 ListImages.Add( new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Your project name;component/Image/ccc.jpg", UriKind.Relative))); 
 ListImages.Add( new BitmapImage(new Uri("/Your project name;component/Image/ddd.jpg", UriKind.Relative))); 

ListImages.ItemsSource =ListImages;
}

 void DisTimer_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
if(SlideCount<=3)
{
listControlImage.SelectedIndex = SlideCount;
SlideCount++;
}
else
   SlideCount=0;
        }






 private void listControlImage_SelectionChanged_1(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
            {
if(listControlImage.SelectedIndex ==-1)
return;
    //Your Navigation code
            }
```